# Pyspark multiple left join on the same conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one main tables with **key1** and **key2** columns.
I need to join this table on many other (*table_1*, *table_2*, ..., *table_n*) on the same conditions `["key1", "key2"]`.
I'm trying something like this.

```
condition = ["key1", "key2"]
df1 = sqlc.sql("SELECT key1, key2 FROM table")
df_1 = sqlc.table("table_1")
df_2 = sqlc.table("table_2")
...
df_n = sqlc.table("table_n")

merged_df = df \
    .join(df_1, condition, how="left") \
    .join(df_2, condition, how="left") \
    ...
    .join(df_n, condition, how="left") \
```

Is there a more efficient, reliable implementation? Maybe using `cache()` or `checkpoint()`?
What is the best practice?
Pyspark version 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to concat the `df_*` into a single `PySpark DataFrame`

```
from functools import reduce

def spark_concat(inp):
  df_complete = reduce(lambda x,y:x.union(y), inp)
  return df_complete


res = []

for tb in ['table1','table2']:
    res += [sqlc.table(tb)]

df_table_complete = spark_concat(res)

condition = ....
merged_df = df.join(df_table_complete, condition, how="left")
```